# Error después de instalar Ninja-IDE. 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy utilizando CentOS 6.7. Acabo de instalar NINJA-IDE para Python, y al ejecutarlo por consola me saca este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja-ide.py", line 34, in <module>
ninja_ide.setup_and_run()
   File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/__init__.py", line 64, in setup_and_run
from ninja_ide import core
   File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/core/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
from ninja_ide.core import file_manager
   File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/core/file_manager.py", line 29, in <module>
     if sys.version_info.major == 3:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Hola @cluna. ¡Bienvenida a [es.so]! ¿En qué versión de Python estás trabajando? Etiquetaste la pregunta como [python-3.x] y [python-2.7] (no pueden ser ambas evidentemente). Si estás con una versión previa, tené en cuenta que ninja funciona en Python 2.7+.

Comment: Como te comenta @Mariano, parece un problema de versiones. ¿Cuál es el Python 3 global que tienes? ¿Cómo lo has instalado? Si Ninja-IDE no es un requerimiento y puedes elegir te aconsejaría probar Spyder, PyCharm,... Parecen IDEs mejor mantenidos y con más funcionalidades.

Comment: Hola, @Mariano,

Al ejecutar python -V dice que utilizo la 2.7.11 (aunque en el pc hay instaladas más versiones). 
Intento instalar Ninja-IDE para probarlo y salir del plugin de netbeans o del idle. PyCharm probé la trial version... Spyder lo he utilizado para computación, pero esta vez buscaba algo más orientado al desarrollo.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar algo como esto

```
    -if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    +if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
```

Parece un error común en algunas aplicaciones de python.

Fuente: https://github.com/anishathalye/dotbot/pull/7

Por otro lado te recomiendo que pruebes SublimeText3 hasta ahora no conozco nadie que no lo ame!

Saludos!